# Gremlin Scala - Bulk Loading of vertices

Tags: gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

we have some 5 different types of vertice labels which will cumulatively have 1 million vertices.

Currently loading full vertices is very bad in performance. Is there a way to do bulk loading with better performance.

I am using DSE 6.0 and we are using graph via gremlin scala.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do bulk loading in DSE Graph 6.0 is with DSE GraphFrames - https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/dseGraphFrameOverview.html

We've seen in internal benchmarks good results with DSE GraphFrames vs. pure Tinkerpop. Have you tried this approach yet?

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan, No I haven't tried it I will look into it.